# Get node name in PHP SimpleXML

Tags: php, xpath

I've alread saw [this question and answer](https://www.google.it/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjJp6OEr__YAhWC_KQKHTMSBLwQFgguMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fstackoverflow.com%2Fquestions%2F7984508%2Fgetting-elements-name-in-xpath&usg=AOvVaw1JgjbDuBDpePv5k8b6rIPm) but I wasn't able to use it.

This is my code:

```
//Get grandparents of MyRefNode
$GrandParents = $MyXml->xpath('//MyRefNode/../..');
//Loop grandparents 
foreach ($GrandParents as $GrandParent){
    //Count each GrandParent's children
    $count = $GrandParent->count(); 
    echo '<br/> Children count = '.$count;
    //Get GrandParent's Tag name **NOT WORKING**
    $TName = $GrandParent->xpath('./name()')
    echo '<br/> Tag Name = '.$TName;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to use [`SimpleXMLElement::getName()`](http://php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.getname.php) instead :

```
foreach ($GrandParents as $GrandParent){
    ....
    $TName = $GrandParent->getName();
    echo '<br/> Tag Name = '.$TName;
}
```